# Is there a Twitter application made with JQuery/JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am wondering if there exist Twitter application (demo) made with JQuery/JQuery mobile?

EDIT: Something that is similar to the official Twitter application, like a clone or something. Or anything close to that.

Comment: Did you not try Google first? I found a jquery twitter ticker example on my first query...

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+twitter+application&qscrl=1

Comment: @anjunatl, what I mean is a Twitter application which is similar to one that is official. Much like a clone of the original or something close to it.

Comment: @xybrek I don't think one exists, and I'm not sure why one would be made since it'd be like recreating the wheel. Have you just tried looking at mobile.twitter.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple I found:

**Twoot, with jQuery and Fluid**
http://www.peterkrantz.com/2008/twitter-client-with-fluid-and-jquery/
*This in-browser application features the primary functions of Twitter and, like demonstrated, could potentially be used as your main Twitter client.*

**ColdFusion & jQuery Twitter Client**
http://www.bennadel.com/projects/kinky-twits.htm
*This is a Twitter client built with ColdFusion and jQuery.*

**jQuery Mobile Twitter Client**
https://github.com/rsepulveda2/Twitter-Mobile
*A web based twitter client using jQuery Mobile and Twitter.*

Also interesting for you to check out:

**jQuery-Twitter Library**
https://github.com/jamescarr/jquery-twitter
*This is a jQuery library optimized to completely harness the capabilities of Twitter. With easy to use functions you could create an advanced Twitter client in no time.*